# Set priorities for the operations. Calculator app

Tags: java, rpn

I'am working on `app` Calculator, using `Stack`, I can't set priorities for the operations.

Using `HashMap` for priorities:

```
 private void addPriorities() {
        priorities.put("*", 3);
        priorities.put("/", 3);
        priorities.put("+", 2);
        priorities.put("-", 2);
        priorities.put("0", 0);
        priorities.put("1", 0);
        priorities.put("2", 0);
        priorities.put("3", 0);
        priorities.put("4", 0);
        priorities.put("5", 0);
        priorities.put("6", 0);
        priorities.put("7", 0);
        priorities.put("8", 0);
        priorities.put("9", 0);
    }
```

`method` to `split` `String` in two `Stacks`, `app` allready working, problem is  priorities for the operations is not working:

```
 public void convertString() {
        arr = expression.split("(?<=[\\d.])(?=[^\\d.])|(?<=[^\\d.])(?=[^\\d.])|(?<=[^\\d.])(?=[\\d.])");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].matches(("[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*"))) {
                digitStack.push(arr[i]);
            }else  if (arr[i].matches("[(]")) {
                characterStack.push(arr[i]);
            }else if (arr[i].matches("[)]")){
                while (!characterStack.peek().matches("[(]")){
                    digitStack.push(characterStack.pop());
                    if (characterStack.peek().matches("[(]")){
                        characterStack.pop();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else if (arr[i].matches("[+=\\-*/^]+")) {
                characterStack.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        unionRevers();
    }
```

in this place:

```
 } else if (arr[i].matches("[+=\\-*/^]+")) {
                characterStack.push(arr[i]);
            }
```

should be something like this - get NullPointerException:

```
 } else if (arr[i].matches("[+=\\-*/^]+") && priorities.get(arr[i]) > priorities.get(characterStack)) {
        while (arr[i].matches("[+=\\-*/^]+") && priorities.get(arr[i]) > priorities.get(characterStack)){
            digitStack.push(characterStack.pop());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Using `Reverse Polish notation`, and `Stack`.

How to set priorities?

Comment: `priorities.get(characterStack)` This doesn't look right. Shouldn't that be `priorities.get(characterStack.pop())`

Comment: Your function seems not to support the shunting yard algorithm to evaluate algebraic notated respectively infix expressions. That would be the only reason to consider the precedence while putting the operands and operators in the correct order on the stack. The operators of any reverse polish notation don't need any precedence information. They are simply executed in the order they are taken from the stack.